# merging records from two tables into third using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables `A`, `B`, `C`

Schema of all 3 tables is same as mentioned below:

```
id, time1, place, xyz, abc, pqrs
```

Now both tables `A` and `B` have many records ( around 10 million)

Now some of the records in A and B are with same `id` and some are with different `Id`

Now I want to merge the records from `A` , and `B` into Table `C`. Merge logic is as follows

```
1)If records with id = someId is present only in A or B ( only in one table)
    then insert record from that table (A/B depending of where its present) in table C
2)If records with id =someId is present in both A and B {

           if(A.time1 > B.time2){
             insert record from A into C
          }else{
             insert record from B into C
          }
    }
```

I want to do it using  a single SQL query , by using outer join between `A` and `B`. But I am not very clear how to go about it.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I think you meant columns not schema

Answer (score 2):

Assuming table `C` is empty, then something like this would do the trick

```
INSERT INTO C           
SELECT A.* 
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE (A.TIME1 > B.TIME1 OR B.TIME1 IS NULL)
UNION 
SELECT B.*
  FROM B LEFT OUTER JOIN A
  ON B.ID = A.ID
 WHERE (A.TIME1 <= B.TIME1 OR A.ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: hmmm.. for the one who down voted.. its ok if u didnt like my answer..but could you plz tell me what exactly you didnt like? If there is a problem with my solution, please let me know

Comment: :Thanks for answering. But this solution only take care of the cases where Both Tables A and B has matching id.What in case if the records exists in A and not in B (or vice versa).We need to insert such data too in C. How can we take care of that?

Comment: @user93796 it does handle the other records (exists in A but not in B and viceversa) thats why its a `left outer join` and a `union`. The left outer join would get all records in A and not in B and in A with time larger/later than B time, same thing with the second query. And the `union` would merge the records

Comment: `OR B.TIME1 IS NULL` and `OR A.ID IS NULL` change nothing since you put it at the `ON`clause level and no record will match those conditions in the joined table. And I think that even records from `A` that have time lower then table `B` will be also selected. So, everything will be selected, excepted those in common since you removed the `ALL` in the `UNION` clause

Comment: @FabienTheSolution The left join would get everything in one but not the other, if something existed in both tables then the `time` comparison would take place and would filter based on that. So I am not sure why you would think that the records mismatching the time condition would be selected?

Comment: @JafarKofahi the left join will take everything that match the condition, but since there is no condition for matching record in table A, the main select, everything will be selected even does that have a lower time.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution aaahhh yes... thanks for pointhing this out

Answer (score 1):

Using `UNION`, you can try something like this :

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.TIME1 > B.TIME1 OR B.ID IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT B.*
FROM B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON B.ID = A.ID 
WHERE B.TIME1 > A.TIME1 OR A.ID IS NULL
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5019b/2/0

Answer (score 0):

combine 3 result sets:

1. records with shared ids.
2. records with ids only present in a
3. records with ids only present in b

1., 2. can be combined into 1 left join, 3. is a right join filtered for unique id occurrence. choose a as data source for 2., b for 3., and a/b depending on precedence for 1.; the selection logic can be compacted to a single condition as the `time1` comparisons will only yield a boolean if none is null, ie. on record from 1.

```
    insert 
      into c ( id, time1, place, xyz, abc, pqrs )
         (
            select id1
                 , time1
                 , place
                 , xyz
                 , abc
                 , pqrs
              from (
                        select a1.id    id1
                             , b1.id    id2
                             , CASE b1.time1 > a1.time1 then b1.time1   else a1.time1   end time1
                             , CASE b1.time1 > a1.time1 then b1.place   else a1.place   end place
                             , CASE b1.time1 > a1.time1 then b1.xyz     else a1.xyz     end xyz
                             , CASE b1.time1 > a1.time1 then b1.abc     else a1.abc     end abc
                             , CASE b1.time1 > a1.time1 then b1.pqrs    else a1.pqrs    end pqrs
                          from a a1
                     left join b b1 on ( b1.id = a1.id )
                         union
                        select b2.id    id1
                             , a2.id    id2
                             , b2.time1
                             , b2.xyz
                             , b2.place
                             , b2.abc  
                             , b2.pqrs                                      , 
                          from b b2
                     left join a a2 on ( a2.id = b2.id )
                         where a2.id is null
                   ) pairs
         )
         ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single request:

```
insert into C
  -- Outer join on B: if B is null null or A has greater time take A
  select case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.id else B.id end,
         case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.time1 else B.time1 end,
         case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.place else B.place end,
         case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.xyz else B.xyz end,
         case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.abc else B.abc end,
         case when B.id is null or A.time1 > B.time1 then A.pqrs else B.pqrs end
  from A, B
  where B.id (+) = A.id
union all
  -- Then get the ones in B and not in A with outer join on A
  select B.id, B.time1, B.place, B.xyz, B.abc, B.pqrs
  from B, A
  where A.id (+) = B.id
    and A.is is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t_c
(
    id_c   NUMBER
,   time_c DATE
);

INSERT
WHEN    id_a IS NULL THEN INTO t_c(id_c, time_c) VALUES (id_b, time_b)
WHEN    id_b IS NULL THEN INTO t_c(id_c, time_c) VALUES (id_a, time_a)
WHEN    id_a = id_b AND time_a >  time_b THEN INTO t_c(id_c, time_c) VALUES (id_a, time_a)
WHEN    id_a = id_b AND time_a <= time_b THEN INTO t_c(id_c, time_c) VALUES (id_b, time_b)
SELECT  *
FROM
(
        SELECT  1 id_a, DATE'2013-01-01' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 id_a, DATE'2013-01-02' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 id_a, DATE'2013-01-03' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 id_a, DATE'2013-01-04' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  7 id_a, DATE'2013-01-07' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  8 id_a, DATE'2013-01-08' time_a FROM dual
) t_a
FULL    JOIN
(
        SELECT  1 id_b, DATE'2013-01-01' time_b FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 id_b, DATE'2013-01-02' time_b FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 id_b, DATE'2013-01-05' time_b FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  6 id_b, DATE'2013-01-06' time_b FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  7 id_a, DATE'2013-01-09' time_a FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT  8 id_a, DATE'2013-01-01' time_a FROM dual
) t_b
ON      t_a.id_a = t_b.id_b
;
/*
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00     1   2013-01-01 00:00:00
2   2013-01-02 00:00:00     2   2013-01-02 00:00:00
                            5   2013-01-05 00:00:00
                            6   2013-01-06 00:00:00
7   2013-01-07 00:00:00     7   2013-01-09 00:00:00
8   2013-01-08 00:00:00     8   2013-01-01 00:00:00
4   2013-01-04 00:00:00     
3   2013-01-03 00:00:00     
*/

SELECT  *
FROM    t_c;
/*
5   2013-01-05 00:00:00
6   2013-01-06 00:00:00
4   2013-01-04 00:00:00
3   2013-01-03 00:00:00
8   2013-01-08 00:00:00
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00
2   2013-01-02 00:00:00
7   2013-01-09 00:00:00
*/
```